# bootstrap less grunt not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, less, gruntjs

I can't seem to get my gruntfile to compile my less files from bootstrap, here is my gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Configuration goes here
  grunt.initConfig({
       less: {
        options: {
            paths: ["public/bower_components/bootstrap/less"]       
        },
        files: {
            "public/css/bootstrap.css" : "public/bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less"
        }   
      } 
  });

  // Load plugins here
  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib");
  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-less");

  // Define your tasks here

};
```

When I run `grunt less` I get

```
Running "less:files" (less) task
Done, without errors.
```

Bootstrap has it's own grunt file that comes with its bower install, I don't suppose it would cause some sort of conflict? I have triple checked my paths and they are fine.

EDIT: my folder structure:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: can you post your structure of the folders and where you save your gruntfile? Seems that you have some problems with sources to the files.

Comment: Hi Slawa, I have posted my folder structure, gruntfile is near the bottom.

Comment: Is it not creating the resulting file, partially creating it, etc?

Comment: I dont believe you need the options.paths here.

Comment: @helion3 it's not creating it at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My grunt less config has blocks for the development and production targets.  Does this work?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Configuration goes here
  grunt.initConfig({
   less: {
      development: {
        options: {
            paths: ["public/bower_components/bootstrap/less"]       
        },
        files: {
            "public/css/bootstrap.css" : "public/bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less"
        }   
      } 
    }
  });

  // Load plugins here
  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib");
  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-less");

  // Define your tasks here

};
```

Comment: Although your paths are correct, I appear to be getting this error `>> No "less" targets found.
Warning: Task "less" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
`

Comment: Oops, added the block in the wrong place.  Just edited to swap the order of `less` and `development`...